# Trying to find horror story: painting that swallows up people during wartime?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I listened to a short horror story reading online a while back, but unfortunately lost my link to the page.

The story is about some people stationed in a cave, somewhere in Europe, during World War II, where they are storing all the valuable paintings from the museum, so they don't get destroyed by bombs and whatnot.

One painting, if I remember correctly, is covered up so no one can look at it, because it swallows up people and makes them disappear when they look into it.

This happens to one of the characters in the story, of course. This ring any bells for anyone?